# PHP is truncating MSSQL Blob data (4096b), even after setting INI values. Am I missing one?

Tags: sql, blob, php, truncation

I am writing a PHP script that goes through a table and extracts the `varbinary(max)` blob data from each record into an external file. The code is working perfectly (I used virtually the same code to go through some images) except when a file is over 4096b - the data is truncated at exactly 4096.

I've modified the values for `mssql.textlimit`, `mssql.textsize`, and `odbc.defaultlrl` without any success.

Am I missing something here?

```
<?php 
 ini_set("mssql.textlimit" , "2147483647");
 ini_set("mssql.textsize" , "2147483647");
 ini_set("odbc.defaultlrl", "0");

 include_once('common.php'); //Connection to DB takes place here.
 $id=$_REQUEST['i'];
 $q = odbc_exec($connect, "Select id,filename,documentBin from Projectdocuments where id = $id"); 
 if (odbc_fetch_row($q)){

  echo "Trying $filename ... ";
  $fileName="projectPhotos/docs/".odbc_result($q,"filename");

  if (file_exists($fileName)){
   unlink($fileName);
  } 

     if($fh = fopen($fileName, "wb")) {
      $binData=odbc_result($q,"documentBin");
         fwrite($fh, $binData) ;
         fclose($fh);
         $size = filesize($fileName);
         echo ("$fileName<br />Done ($size)<br><br>");
     }else {
      echo ("$fileName Failed<br>");
     }
 } 
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

> Trying ... projectPhotos/docs/file1.pdf
>   Done (4096)
>
> Trying ... projectPhotos/docs/file2.zip Done (4096)
>
> Trying ...
>   projectPhotos/docsv3.pdf Done (4096)
>
> etc..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of setting `odbc.defaultlrl` to `0`, try setting it to an actual value instead:

```
ini_set("odbc.defaultlrl", "100K");
```

Comment: This turned out to be the correct answer, but I though using `0` was as good as not putting a limit at all... even if that werent the case, why would it still limit at 4096? weird. Thanks! Do you have any idea what the max value for this is?

Comment: `0` is invalid, so it didn't override the existing value.

Comment: 2.5 years later I had this problem AGAIN - and re-found this old post. Funny.

Comment: Actually `0` *is* valid, but it means "passthru".

Answer (score 5):

If you're using mssql (freetds), look in /etc/freetds.conf for a setting called "text size".  Mine was set to 64512 and that's exactly what my images were being truncated to.  I set it to 5MB (5242880) and it's working like a charm now.

```
text size = 5242880
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this comment in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php#97848), you must set the INI settings **before connecting**, which does not seem to be your case.

Comment: My connection is being made in `common.php` so I think this is probably not the issue, unless I am missing something. I will update my post to reflect the connection's location. Thanks for the input though (I did not down-vote you).

Comment: @Dutchie432: Don't worry about it. (-2 reputation OMG!!) Downvoter should read the FAQ. :) Anyway, still according to the comments in the PHP manual, the code in Jordan answer's above seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is ancient, but I solved this differently. ini_set does not wok for mssql.textlimit or mssql.textsize, this is documented on php.net.

Both of these default to 4096b (4k) in the php.ini file. Reset these to a higher value and it will work fine.

Dont forget to restart httpd service after.

Comment: Ancient, but still relevant!  One thing to add to this is to tell MSSQL the limit you set for PHP.  Issue the sql statement BEFORE your query:  SET TEXTLIMIT <size>