# PHP fwrite and file_put_contents create partial damaged tif and pdf files

Tags: php, pdf, tiff

I have a database with images in it (yes I know it makes me cringe too, not my choice) and I am retrieving the 'image' type and writing out the files to a directory. Based on the mime type in the database it tells me if it should be a tif or a pdf.

The process works just as it should on one server but not the other; however, there are differences between the servers shown below:

Server 1 - Works:

- Ubuntu 12.04.5
- PHP 5.3.1

Server 2 - Does not work:

- Ubuntu 16.04.2
- PHP 7.0.18

I have tried both `fwrite` and `file_put_contents` with both ways just creating the file in the directory at 63KB (while the server that works creates a 773KB file and opens as it should). The file directory is owned by www-data and can be written into just like the first server. For testing I also gave root permissions to the directory and ran in both the browser and command line with the same results. I have also matched up everything that looked like it could relate in the PHP ini files.

I could not find any kind of changelog for those functions from PHP 5 to 7. Is there anything else that anyone could suggest I try looking into?

Comment: So what is the size/content difference between good and bad file?

Comment: Maybe the environment that runs the PHP process has`ulimit -f 64` set?

Comment: Don't you suspect the database code? Retrieving BLOBs from databases often requires using some APIs that are not straightforward, or playing with database server settings, but you don't even mention whether it's SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL...

Comment: @AbraCadaver - The size for the one that doesn't work comes out to 63KB and for the one that works 638KB for the tif and 773 KB for the pdf.

Comment: @AlexHowansky - I checked and it said unlimited

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - My apologies the database is an SQL Server. I didn't include that information because that's not where the problem seems to lie as the original program on Server 1 has been working this way fine for years.

Comment: Alright. There're many questions here about [data truncation in SQL Server blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500506/php-is-truncating-mssql-blob-data-4096b-even-after-setting-ini-values-am-i-m) anyway.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - Boom, solid link. While the accepted answer was not what I needed one of the ones below was it. There is a text size field in the freetds config file that needed to be increased. That did it perfectly, thank you so much. If you want to leave that as answer feel free so I can accept. Thanks again to you and everyone else!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. Let's just link questions together.