# Issue while handling PNG image from MSSQL database

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm having trouble saving/viewing a PNG file stored in a MsSQL database, as follows:

I'm using the next code to get the file:

```
function manualDIRECTimg(){
ini_set('mssql.textlimit', '100000000');
ini_set('mssql.timeout', '9999');
ini_set('mssql.compatability_mode', '1');
ini_set('mssql.textsize', '100000000');
set_time_limit(0);
header('Content-Type: image/png');

$codPRODUSerp = $_GET['id'];

$rowerp=mssql_fetch_array(mssql_query("EXECUTE spWEBSelectFoto ".$codPRODUSerp.", 1"));
$img=$rowerp['0'];  // The image is stored in column0

if($img!=''){

global $defaultPRODUCTimagePATH;
$imagineprodusTMP = $defaultPRODUCTimagePATH.'_0_TMPzz.jpg';

$file = fopen( $imagineprodusTMP, "w" );
fwrite( $file, $img);
fclose( $file);
readfile($imagineprodusTMP);
unlink($imagineprodusTMP);
}else{echo "There's no image found in the database";}

}
```

but the output is a image that get's "cut" after 10% ... this behavior does not occur when pulling a JPG image from MsSQL ... any ideas?

I've tried using while loop, but that ends up with a HUGE file probably because it's left in the loop state until a serverside limit kicks in (script execution time etc.)

```
while($rowerp=mssql_fetch_array(mssql_query("EXECUTE spWEBSelectFoto ".$codPRODUSerp.", 1"))){ echo $rowerp['0']; }  //with the appropiate headers...
```

and even if i encode the $img string i still get the same result when trying a PNG image... https://pastebin.com/ce6ndFai

Again JPG/JPEG images are OK... this issue occurs only on PNGs

P.S. Actual files are as follow:
[image]  (a OK pulled and saved JPEG image)

[image] (BAD PNG ...)

And it's not a question of original (database) image size in kb neighter it's size in pixels, i've got a small 500x500px and a 1000x1000px PNG acting the same way. I must say that the stored image works fine when the actual software that's using it outputs it right:
[image]

Comment: What is the data type and length of the field you are storing to in SQL Server?

Comment: I'm sorry but you will have to help me a bit more, i'm totaly unfamiliar with PHP-MSSQL ... the developers of the ERP software used in my case gave me a set of instructions with functions that pulls out data from the MS SQL server, in this case EXECUTE spWEBSelectFoto ".$codPRODUSerp.", 1 ... where codPRODUSerp is an unique identifier and 1 is the 1st image in a set of 10 (in my case only file numer1 is used)

Comment: I do not know how to get the datatype nor length stored in the cell, and i use [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) to browse MySQL, MSSQL servers... tho i've saved an "export" made by Adminer for a PNG... if it helps [sql export](https://ufile.io/om310)  (CSV with , as delimiter)

Comment: Can you run the following on the SQL server and present the results (no quotes)? "sp_helptext spWEBSelectFoto"

Comment: Query executed OK, -1 rows affected. (0.012 s)

The developers gave me the following help:

Comment: The developers gave me the following help:
spWEBSelectFoto
\@CodStoc int, \@Number int
If the \@Numar parameter receives values from 1 to 10 then returns a photo from 1 to 10, if it receives values from 101 to 104 will return the documentation file from 1 to 4

they said that it's a PHP Programming issue and it's not theyr job to help... so thats why i ended up here..

Comment: This is happening because your database stack can't handle data that's more than 64K (2^16 bytes); data is cut off at that point. The JPEG image fits within this limit, the PNG image does not. As to where exactly that fails I couldn't say. The `mssql_*` functions are ancient and rely on even more ancient access libraries. Try the libraries provided by [Microsoft themselves](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1258.accessing-sql-server-databases-from-php.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Jeroen Mostert, your answer sounds logic enough... As the script is ran on a shared hosting server i can't say i can load my own php-mssql libraries, i must use the native ones... I'll keep my question unanswered for the moment mabe someone has a ideea, but in the end i'll have to consider my question answered. Thanks!

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32404785/4137916). You could try the ODBC module, if that's available, but if everything is ultimately using FreeTDS and that's misconfigured, your host *will* have to change things. It's really too bad so few people are using the MSSQL ODBC drivers for Linux, which have none of these problems. If all else fails you could petition your developers to give you a special stored procedure that serves the data in chunks, but it's exceedingly ugly/inconvenient, and you will probably not make friends that way.

Comment: Have you tried a small image, like 32x32 pixels so that you can easily confirm this is a size issue? As already stated, mssql_* is long deprecated, not even present in current versions of PHP. Do you have PDO or sqlsrv_* functions installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a while i've found the problema causing the image beeing truncated, in my initial tests i've used a simple

ini_set('mssql.textlimit', '5242880');
ini_set('mssql.textsize', '5242880');

which did not make any impact, thus transfered data was truncated after 60KB... after some research i've found that manually setting

mssql_query("SET TEXTSIZE 5242880");

before the actual mssql_fetch_array query, solved my issue!
thus instructing MSSQL that the TEXTLIMIT & TEXTSIZE will be overwritten insures a complete data transfer between sql and php

Thank you all for your wisdom!

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of problems here, such as your use of global variables and deprecated database functions, and an unnecessarily labourious method for output. Here's how I would approach this:

```
// database is passed as a parameter; assume it's PDO:
// $db = new PDO("mssql:host=db_host;dbname=db_name");
// ID is also passed to the function instead of using a global

function manualDIRECTimg($db, $id) {
    $sql    = "EXECUTE spWEBSelectFoto ?, 1";
    $params = array($id);
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($sql, $params);
    $stmt->exec();
    if ($img = $stmt->fetchColumn()) {
        // Are all of these images guaranteed to be PNG?
        // If not you'll need to adjust this as needed
        header("Content-Type: image/png");
        echo $img;
        return true;
    }    
    return false;
}
```

If your database takes more than the default script timeout to fetch one image,
bring it up with the DB admins. Users won't wait 60 seconds for one picture, and disabling timeouts is not a reasonable approach!

Definitely ditch those old mssql functions though. They're long deprecated and aren't even present in modern versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems it's a question of how data is delivered by the SQL server, i've managed to change a bit to miken32's code and endend up with:

```
function manualPDOdirectIMG() {
set_time_limit(0);
$codPRODUSerp = $_GET['id'];
$db = new PDO("dblib:host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;dbname=DATABASE", "USER", "PWD");
    $sql    = "EXECUTE spWEBSelectFoto ".$codPRODUSerp.", 1";
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($img = $stmt->fetchColumn()) {
        header("Content-Type: image/png");
        echo $img;
        return true;
    }    
    return false;
}
```

and the same "cut" image results...

it's been amazing to feel helped by all of you!

As far as my question, the answer is:

In this case it's a issue with remote MSSQL missconfiguration.