# Why are all of my images getting cut off when I pull the binary out of a SQL Server DB?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, binary-data

I'm using PDO in PHP 7 on an Amazon Linux AMI to connect to a SQL Server DB running on Amazon RDS.

Thus far, I've been able to extract all of the data out of the DB just fine except for one column in one table. The column is of the type `image` and contains binary data.

When I attempt to use PDO in PHP to select from the column in question and then output the binary to the browser window with the necessary header sent (e.g., `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`), I can only see a part of the file (in the case of an image) or I get a corrupt-file error (in the case of a PDF).

In a few edge cases (I'm presuming when the file size is quite small), I can see the full image, but that's rare.

The following is an example of this problem in Chrome:

[image]

I've done some pretty extensive Googling on this issue, but there doesn't seem to be a lot of info on this issue, and all the pages I've seen are quite old and related to either `mssql` (no longer available in PHP 7) or `sqlsrv` drivers.

Here are some examples of (seemingly) related pages I've found:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/m6v1t/need_help_displaying_jpg_from_mssql_image_field/
- https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/blob-display-is-truncated/
- [PHP is truncating MSSQL Blob data (4096b), even after setting INI values. Am I missing one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500506/php-is-truncating-mssql-blob-data-4096b-even-after-setting-ini-values-am-i-m)

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening and how I can fix it? I feel like PDO should be able to handle this, but if there is an issue with PDO and I need to use some other drivers to handle this, that's fine too.

Thank you.

Comment: Show your table schema

Comment: You should be storing a reference [file path] to these files instead of storing them in your database. say some one uploaded a 1GB file ... now that's in your database ... that's no good.

Comment: cmorrissey, I agree with you 100%, but in this case, I inherited the DB from someone else and I'm literally in the process of trying to get all the data out to better organize it. To do that though, I need to get the binary file data out first though so that I can save it into files, thus my question above.

Comment: aynber, the table schema is something I probably should not be showing publicly. If you'd like the metadata on the binary column in the one table specifically, I could anonymize the column name, etc. and present that. Would that be sufficient?

Comment: That's fine. Or just tell us what the datatype of the image column is, that's the important part.

Comment: The `DATA_TYPE` is `image` and `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` and `CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH` are `2147483647`. `COLUMN_DEFAULT` is blank and `IS_NULLABLE` is `YES`. All other relevant metadata is blank.

Comment: Try executing `SET TEXTSIZE = -1` as a separate query first?

Comment: miken32, I had to remove the equals sign to get it to work, but it didn't matter. `TEXTSIZE` was originally set to `2147483647` (2 GB) anyway, so setting it to `-1` wouldn't make a difference. Most of the files I'm dealing with aren't more than a megabyte or two each. Still not sure how to handle this. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Can you confirm that images in your database column are not already truncated?

Comment: Alex, I just discovered what you were eluding to. I was viewing the data from SSMS, and I noticed that all the columns were cut off at 64k. I was able to add `FOR XML PATH('')` (or some other XML/JSON variation) at the end of the query to get the full column of data to be output in XML format with the data itself in base64 format. I was able to convert the base64 string to binary to view the full image. Now I just need to figure out how to write a PDO query in PHP to actually get that XML out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer. The data coming back to PHP via PDO was in fact being truncated at 64k, thus causing issues.

Alex helped lead me on the right path by suggesting setting `TEXTSIZE` to `-1`. The rookie mistake that I made was that I did `SET TEXTSIZE -1` from Microsoft SSMS, assuming that it would be set globally for all connections, which was not the case. It only set it for the SSMS connection, thus the problem.

However, when I finally did the following in PDO in PHP, that is, set `TEXTSIZE` to `-1` with the PDO connection and then make the query from PDO, I was able to set `TEXTSIZE` for the PDO connection and then get back all the data:

```
doSqlServerQuery("SET TEXTSIZE -1;");

$results = doSqlServerQuery("SELECT binary-data-image-column AS data 
  FROM table-name 
  WHERE key = 95948578934578934;");

//Function definition

function doSqlServerQuery($query, $dbh = null) {
  if (!isset($dbh)) {
    global $dbh;
  }

  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

  if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->execute();

    $results = [];
    while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $results[] = $result;
    }

    return $results;
  } else {
    pO($dbh->errorInfo());
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad you got this sorted. Had you @ replied to my comment I would have been able to provide the same answer for you!

Comment: Wasn't aware that that was how the @ symbol worked on SO. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed this myself, it is being cut off after 64KB has been uploaded, to fix this, either set a limit at 64KB or change it to a longblob, which gives you 4 gigabytes of storage instead of 64 kilobytes.