# Change max size of odbc_exec() return

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I'm doing a procedure call to `SQL Server` from `PHP ODBC`. One of the fields on the procedure returns has a lot of text. The code runs with no erros, but the text read by `odbc` in my code comes incomplete.

```
$result = odbc_exec($db, "{CALL myprocedure(2, 3)}");
while(odbc_num_rows($result)) {
  $m[] = odbc_fetch_array($result);
  var_dump($m);
}
```

I got this return of `var_dump($m)`:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["mensagem"]=> string(4096) "
```

I want change the max size that can get from a field with `PHP ODBC`. How I can do this from my code?

I don't have access to `php.ini` file on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/odbc.configuration.php the only variable with 4096 is "odbc.defaultlrl". According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4500598/4934937, `ini_set("odbc.defaultlrl", "100K");` should do the trick.